# Storing thread specific variables appropriately

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, hashtable, binary-search

I am in a process of restructuring an existing application code. One of the requirements of this restructuring is that I need to store a thread specific variable which would be referred pretty often for both read and write. I would be having approximately 50 such threads. The thread specific variable would basically be a pointer to a structure.
Here, I am not able to decide how exactly should I store this variable. Should I make it thread specific key which could be accessed by `pthread_getspecific/pthread_setspecific`? But I came across some posts which say that calls to these are pretty slow. Then another approach could be of having a global structure which store all these thread specific pointers in either a sorted array (to use binary search) or a hash table of elements in key-value form. Key would be mostly constant (thread_id) and value could be changed frequently. Again what would be the best approach here?
I know the fastest access to the required value would be to actually pass this pointer to each function and keep propagating it. But that would require a lot of code rewrite which I want to avoid.
Thanks in advance for you response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the gcc toolchain (some other compilers as well), you have a third option. Use the [__thread](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/thread.htm) storage class specifier. This is very efficient. It works by isolating the thread local storage items into separate VM page(s), which get switched when a thread is scheduled. This way each thread is able to point to its own copy of the variables. The cost is just one operation per thread schedule, without the per key lookup cost for other approaches.

Comment: That seems to be a good option. I will explore more about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your threads are static (that is, you launch them, and they do not exit unless the program is exiting), then you can simply use any mapping structure that you care about. The only trick is that the map needs to be populated before all the threads are allowed to run. So, you probably need a mutex and condition variable to block all the threads until the map is populated. After that, you can broadcast to all the waiting threads to go. Since the map will never change after that, each thread can read from it without any contention to retrieve their thread specific information.

If you are using GCC, then you can use a compiler specific extension. The `__thread` storage class extension places a global variable in a thread specific area, so that each thread has their own copy of that global.

```
__thread struct info_type *info;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't optimize prematurely, measure performance of the standard approach before you do anything. They shouldn't use more than some 100 clock cycles on average to provide you with the thread specific pointer. In many applications this is not much distinguishable from noise.

Then, I doubt that any portable solution that you can come with that goes through some sort of global variable or function can be faster than the POSIX functions. Basically they don't do much else than you propose, but are probably better optimized.

The best option that you have is to realize your data on the stack of each thread and pass a pointer to that data through to the functions that need it.

If you have a C11 compliant compiler (I think clang already implements that part) you can use the `_Thread` construct that provides you with exactly the type of variable that you want. Other compilers (pre-C11) have such features with extensions, e.g. the gcc family of compilers have it with `__thread`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. Is the structure meant to be thread specific? the one your pointer is pointing at?
If yes, then what is the problem in having a thread specific structure? if it is meant to be shared, (50 threads simultaneously!) you can have a global variable although synchronising might lead to problems as to which ones updating the value. 
Why do you want a pointer to all thread-specific data?

Comment: The structure is not thread specific, hence using the pointer. Very true that there would be synchronization issues. Will have to implement some mechanism to overcome it.

Comment: You can broadcast to all threads once the data has changed. the broadcasting controlling mutexes will lead to a thread segment that refreshes the value. for instance,

"thread 1
mutex 1
critical section

/*broadcast section
calls thread X that has the update sequence
*/



Since each thread gets their own copy of global data, you can use shared memory maybe.